# How to bold part of the text in dbgrid?

Tags: delphi, fonts, styles, dbgrid

I'm using Delphi XE2, is there a way to set bold font style on part of the text in DBGrid?
For example, when I search for something, I want something like this.

[image]

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Yes it is. You'll have to use custom drawing though, there's no individual properties you can set to do so.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
procedure TForm1.DBGrid1DrawColumnCell(Sender: TObject; const Rect: TRect;
DataCol: Integer; Column: TColumn; State: TGridDrawState);
begin
  if (Column.Field.FieldName = 'Pay') then
  begin
    if Column.Field.AsString = 'yes' then
    begin
      dbgrid1.Canvas.Font.Color := clBlue;
      dbgrid1.Canvas.Font.Style :=[fsBold];
      dbgrid1.Canvas.FillRect(Rect);
      dbgrid1.DefaultDrawColumnCell(Rect, DataCol, Column, State);
    end
    else
    begin
      dbgrid1.Canvas.Font.Color:= clRed;
      dbgrid1.Canvas.FillRect(Rect);
      dbgrid1.DefaultDrawColumnCell(Rect, DataCol, Column, State);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Is there a way to repaint dbgrid, while changing text property of edit, so I can get dbgrid to be drawn again?

Comment: how you are using? Are you searching by content of Tedit and return the data on dbgrid? Is Dynamic?

Comment: Exactly, it's dynamic.

Comment: You can close your dataset and open again (in search) with the filter that you want, because this command is for drawcolumncell. 

I don't know other way of to do it...

Comment: Yes, somehow i managed to get it to work.
But there is only one problem, if you look at my example, second row, first column, 14358. How I can change font style to bold, but not on whole string (example: **14358**), but only on matched criteria (example: 1 **4358**), like on the image?

Comment: you can see the devexpress components (Tcxgrid). Is a good grid, with various resources...

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem, set the value of the propertie DefaultDrawing of the DBGrid to False.

I had the same problem for me and solved .